# Is it possible to combine 2 or more textures VIA - BelnderKit add-on

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, texture-painting

I am trying to make a grassy landscape with a dirt path through it using two different textures found through the BlenderKit add-on. [It's an add-on that lets you search and quickly import assets, materials and brushes into your project]

How would I go about doing this? Example of a 'grass' texture and 'clay dirt'

[image]

Is it possible to paint one onto another where the edges of the 'path' would blend in with the grass?

The closest I have gotten is: [image]

which gets me this result: [image]

Comment: You could use a third texture to map the transition between the two make it black and white and plug that into the fac of the rgb mix, or even better, have two different principled bsdfs with different roughnesses and use the third texture to control the fac of a mix shader node.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nascent for the awnser.

You just add a new image texture node. Click new and name it. Then add that to the 'fac' of the MixRGB node. Then all you have to do is go into the texture paint tab and make sure you have your new texture selected (I named mine Dirt_Path_PAINT) and draw over your texture in the UV section or for easy use right in the viewport!
[image]

[image]

[image]